# Is put_block_blob_from_path depreciated?

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm currently trying to upload some files to my Azure storage, but can't seem to achieve that.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
data1File=os.path.join(filePath,'data1.csv')
data2File=os.path.join(filePath,'data2.csv')
blockBlobService = BlockBlobService(account_name='NAME', account_key='KEY')
blockBlobService.put_block_blob_from_path('HdiNotebooks/Recommendation_Systems/data/full', 'data1.csv', data1File)
blockBlobService.put_block_blob_from_path('HdiNotebooks/Recommendation_Systems/data/full', 'data2.csv', data2File)
```

However, I get this error thrown to me:

AttributeError: 'BlockBlobService' object has no attribute 'put_block_blob_from_path'

The code example I had seen previously looked like this:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobService
data1File=os.path.join(filePath,'data1.csv')
data2File=os.path.join(filePath,'data2.csv')
blockBlobService = BlobService(account_name='NAME', account_key='KEY')
blockBlobService.put_block_blob_from_path('HdiNotebooks/Recommendation_Systems/data/full', 'data1.csv', data1File)
blockBlobService.put_block_blob_from_path('HdiNotebooks/Recommendation_Systems/data/full', 'data2.csv', data2File)
```

However, already in the first line I got the error that there is no such module as "BlobService". I have gone through the azure package github, but couldn't figure out where is my mistake.

I'm currently trying to run this code on a Windows machine and Python 3.6.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reviewed the versions of Azure Storage SDK for Python, the version of the APIs you used is less than [`0.20.3`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/tree/v0.20.3), and the APIs have changed from version `0.30.0`.

You can check your current version via `pip freeze | grep azure-storage`.

If you want to the old version, you need to first remove the current one via `pip uninstall azure-storage` and reinstall via `pip install azure-storage==0.20.3`.

If not, please try to upgrade to the newest one via `pip install --upgrade azure-storage` and refer to the newest offical [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-python-how-to-use-blob-storage) & the latest API [reference](http://azure-storage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to use new APIs.

Answer (score 0):

```
container_name = "flask"
    storage_acc_name = ""
    storage_acc_key = "5MsH80Uea3K/0VIH7LMAsqvHnXIWbrADi9KOhqyYA/3VxL1/VuWVbi1sl15magDT0fz6UR5xj2DH+AStwGrs2Q=="
    service = BlobServiceClient(account_name=storage_acc_name, account_key=storage_acc_key)
    # Dump data into azure blob
    service.put_block_blob_from_path(container_name, "data.json", json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).