# write files to azure blob storage (directory)

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to write APIs csv result to Azure BLOB Storage using python 3.7.

BLOB path: BLOB_ACCOUNT/CONTAINER_NAME/FOLDER_NAME/Files

I'm trying to write files into directory 
e.g. new files should be created into   BLOB_ACCOUNT/CONTAINER_NAME/FOLDER_NAME/File1
                                        BLOB_ACCOUNT/CONTAINER_NAME/FOLDER_NAME/File2 ..

I checked method of blob service, but not sure how to specify directory name to file path.

```
blob_service.put_block_blob_from_path(container_name, file_name, file_path)
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `put_block_blob_from_path` is very old and please upgrade your azure storage sdk to latest version(you can follow [this](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-blob/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44541501/is-put-block-blob-from-path-depreciated?answertab=active#tab-top) article), and you should use 
`blobservice.create_blob_from_path` method in the latest sdk.

> but not sure how to specify directory name to file path

the **file name** should be the **directory_name/file_name**, like FOLDER_NAME/File1. For example, I want to upload local file to storage_account/container_name/directory_name(eg. test1)/aa.txt, I can use the code below:

```
blobservice.create_blob_from_path("samples-workitems","test1/aa.txt","D:\\temp\\aa.txt")
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
let me check this and will come back for any questions.